# Increment the string representation of a number, while retaining leading zeroes

Tags: c#

I am trying to increment the value of 0001 to 0002. I've tried integers, but that rounds it off to 2. I have also tried to add floats, with the same effect:

```
float newInt = float.Parse("0001") + float.Parse("0001");
```

How would one increment numbers formatted as 0001?

Comment: `0001` is not a number. It's a string. Numbers don't have leading zeros. You would increment `0001` by parsing it as an integer, incrementing it, and then convert it back to a string with a format that would provide the leading zeros.

Comment: @Ken, in fairness, `0001` _is_ a number in C#, but it's no different to `1`. I'm assuming that you meant `"0001"`.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Yes, I did mean `"0001"`. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should keep your values and your formatting *separate* from one another <sup>(a)</sup>.

Simply maintain an integer variable and, when you want it displayed as width four, left padded with zeros, just use something like:

```
String sNum = num.ToString("D4");
```

as per the following complete program:

```
using System;

namespace test {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            int x = 8;
            x++; Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("D4"));
            x++; Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("D4"));
            x++; Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("D4"));
            Console.ReadLine();  // just because I'm in the IDE.
        }
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
0009
0010
0011
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> You can certainly *do* what you ask, with something like:

```
using System;

namespace test {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            String s = "0008";
            s = (Int32.Parse(s) + 1).ToString("D4"); Console.WriteLine(s);
            s = (Int32.Parse(s) + 1).ToString("D4"); Console.WriteLine(s);
            s = (Int32.Parse(s) + 1).ToString("D4"); Console.WriteLine(s);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

But you should be aware that continuously converting a string back to an integer to increment it, then back to a string to display it, is needlessly inefficient. If one of my minions bought me that code for a review, well, I can't *tell* you the fun I'd have tearing it apart :-)

Answer (score -2):

```
String sNum = num.ToString("0000");
```